# liferay-ui:input-move-boxes get List from action

Tags: java, jsp, action, liferay, portlet

I cane get ArrayList from my.jsp to action.java

my.jsp

```
<%
List left = new ArrayList(), right = new ArrayList(), l = new ArrayList();
left.add(new KeyValuePair("1key", "item1value"));
left.add(new KeyValuePair("4key", "item4value"));
left.add(new KeyValuePair("3key", "item3value"));
right.add(new KeyValuePair("2key", "item2value"));
%>
<aui:form action="<%= editListURL %>" method="post">
<liferay-ui:input-move-boxes
    leftBoxName="left"
    leftTitle="Left box"
    leftList="<%=left %>"
    rightBoxName="right"
    rightTitle="Right box"
    rightList="<%=right %>"     
/>
<aui:button type="submit" value="send"/>
</aui:form>
```

action.java

```
public void setSelectMyStdudent(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        try{
            String left = "";
            left = actionRequest.getParameter("left");
            if(left.isEmpty() || left == "" || left == null) {
                System.out.println("left EMPTY");
                left = "0";
            } else {
                KeyValuePair pair = new KeyValuePair();
                pair.setKey(left);
                System.out.println("left = " + left);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

This is code don't work(.
Please help me to do this questions.
How right get key from jsp file?

Comment: Little confusing. Did you get the left value? Are you also looking for right value?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, the only question is whether your "setSelectMyStdudent" is actually being called.

Where are you defining:

```
<%= editListURL %>
```

As for this to work it should be definied like:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editListURL " name="setSelectMyStudent" />
```

Also you know you have a typo where you have "setSelectMyStdudent" should probably be "setSelectMyStudent". I have corrected this in my example.

Let me know if this helps or if you have any more questions.